# Replace dynamic text SQL

Tags: sql, design-patterns, dynamic, replace

Can anyone help me with a little problem I can't solve. I am trying to update a bbcode tag in php_text

```
Exemple [i] => [i:rlj7bc53]
Exemple [u] => [u:rlj7bc53]
Exemple [b] => [/b:rlj7bc53]
```

And also

```
[quote="Christo"] => [quote=&quot;Christo&quot;:rlj7bc53]
```

for the moment i have used this request.

```
update phpbb_posts
   set post_text = replace(post_text, '[/quote]' , '[/quote:rlj7bc53]')
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? For example, Oracle has regexp_replace which is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it before you run the update:

```
SELECT post_text as [OldTag]
      ,'[' + SUBSTRING(post_text, 2, (LEN(post_text) - 2)) + ':rlj7bc53]' AS [NewTag]
FROM phpbb_posts
```

The actual update:

```
UPDATE phpbb_posts
SET post_text = '[' + SUBSTRING(post_text, 2, (LEN(post_text) - 2)) + ':rlj7bc53]'
```

Please note that his will update ALL text between [ and ] on that column by adding :rlj7bc53 to it.
If you want to replace ONLY specific tags on the column, you can do something like this:

```
  UPDATE phpbb_posts
  SET post_text = '[' + SUBSTRING(post_text, 2, (LEN(post_text) - 2)) + ':rlj7bc53]'
  WHERE post_text = [i]
     OR post_text = [u]
     OR post_text = [/quote]
```

Comment: I know it has been nearly 3 years, but please mark the answer as correct if it has helped you :)